How to change default sound volume over Remote Desktop
Seems like by default I can only have no sound at all or system sounds at 100%. Even when I lower volume of system sounds (in the System -> Audio -> Mixer) it still resets back to 100% when re-connected with RDP.
Is there something I can tweak in the .rdp file? Or maybe something I can tweak with regedit? Or some fancy program I can download or buy that does that for me?
I'm using Windows 11 on both ends.
